# ValueError using scipy.optimize on multidimensional function

Tags: python

What am i doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so

def f(z):
  return z


guess=np.array([1,1])
z0=so.newton(f,guess)
```

Im getting the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

There is some info on scipy docs about vectorizing the function if its domain is multivalued, but cant quite understand what i have to do.

Comment: Are you sure you want your function to return an array as well (rather than a single value)?

Comment: Your code snippet works in python3 (giving `z0 = array([0., 0.])`), but not in python2.

Comment: Im using Python3.6 on Spyder from university... hmm

Comment: What version do you use of scipy (I am on 1.2.1) and numpy (1.15.4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code with an older version of the lib (`Python 3.6.3`, `scipy 1.1.0`), then I get the same error that you showed in your question.

When I upgrade to a newer version (same python, `scipy 1.2.1`) then the error goes away and the code runs fine.